# Counting ED (emergency department) visits but only one per 8 day period

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working in MS SQL Server 2017 on counting member ED visits where a member may go months between ER visits or may have multiple consecutive days each with a visit.  The rule that I am trying to calculate is this:

> If a member has more than one ED visit in an 8-day period, include
> only the first eligible ED visit. For example, if a member has an
> eligible ED visit on January 1, include the January 1 visit and do not
> include ED visits that occur on or between January 2 and January 8.
> Then, if applicable, include the next eligible ED visit that occurs on
> or after January 9. Identify visits chronologically, including only
> one visit per 8-day period.

If the days since the last visit is NULL or >= 8 then that is always counted and I have that.  The issue I am having is how to look at the running total of Days_Since_Last_Visit to find the next valid visit when there are multiple in a given 8 day period.

In the example below the rows marked in green are flagged for inclusion because the Days_Since_Last_Visit is NULL or >= 8.
The rows highlighted yellow are the ones that should be counted as the first valid visit in the next 8 day period.  The bold outline shows the days that are adding up to reach the threshold of 8.

[Example data with highlighted entries that should be counted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEJof.png)

I have prepared the SQL for the example in the image hoping someone can help me get unstuck.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Example') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #Example

CREATE TABLE 
    #Example (
        Subscriber_ID VARCHAR(16),
        Member_Seq VARCHAR(2),
        Measurement_Year INT,
        Visit_Date DATETIME,
    )

INSERT INTO #Example (Subscriber_ID,Member_Seq,Measurement_Year,Visit_Date) VALUES
    ('788768646','02','2019','2019-07-09'),
    ('788768646','02','2019','2019-08-05'),
    ('788768646','02','2019','2019-08-18'),
    ('788768646','02','2019','2019-09-13'),
    ('788768646','02','2019','2019-09-15'),
    ('788768646','02','2019','2019-09-19'),
    ('788768646','02','2019','2019-09-25'),
    ('788768646','02','2019','2019-10-14'),
    ('788768646','02','2019','2019-10-21'),
    ('788768646','02','2019','2019-10-24'),
    ('788768646','02','2019','2019-10-27'),
    ('788768646','02','2019','2019-10-28'),
    ('788768646','02','2019','2019-11-03'),
    ('788768646','02','2019','2019-11-06'),
    ('788768646','02','2019','2019-11-18'),
    ('788768646','02','2019','2019-12-11')

    SELECT  y.Subscriber_ID,
            y.Member_Seq,
            y.Measurement_Year,
            y.Visit_Date,
            y.Prior_Visit_Date,
            y.Days_Since_Last_Visit,
            CASE
                WHEN Days_Since_Last_Visit >= 8 OR Days_Since_Last_Visit IS NULL THEN
                    'Y'
                ELSE
                    NULL
                END Include_Visist,
            CASE 
                WHEN Days_Since_Last_Visit >= 8 OR Days_Since_Last_Visit IS NULL THEN
                    NULL
                ELSE
                    SUM (CASE 
                            WHEN Days_Since_Last_Visit >= 8 OR Days_Since_Last_Visit IS NULL THEN 
                                NULL
                            ELSE 
                                y.Days_Since_Last_Visit 
                            END
                        ) OVER (PARTITION BY y.Subscriber_ID, y.Member_Seq,y.Measurement_Year ORDER BY y.Visit_Date)
                END Running_Total
    FROM    (
            SELECT  x.Subscriber_ID,
                    x.Member_Seq,
                    x.Measurement_Year,
                    x.Visit_Date,
                    LAG(Visit_Date) OVER (
                        PARTITION BY x.Subscriber_ID, x.Member_Seq, x.Measurement_Year
                        ORDER BY x.Visit_Date) Prior_Visit_Date,
                    DATEDIFF(DAY,
                                LAG(Visit_Date) OVER (
                                    PARTITION BY x.Subscriber_ID, x.Member_Seq, x.Measurement_Year
                                    ORDER BY x.Visit_Date),
                                x.Visit_Date) Days_Since_Last_Visit
            FROM #Example x
            ) y
```

Comment: Please include a tag for your database dialect as that will often determine how an answer is developed. I suspect this may require a recursive query.

Comment: Updated with the correct tag and the example code cleaned up.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was challenging. I added some additional test records to make sure it handled a long string of visits close together over several periods.

```
WITH Example as (
    SELECT Subscriber_ID, Member_Seq, Measurement_Year, CAST(Visit_Date as datetime) as [Visit_Date]
    FROM (
        VALUES
            ('788768646','02','2019','2019-06-01'),
            ('788768646','02','2019','2019-06-09'),
            ('788768646','02','2019','2019-07-09'),
            ('788768646','02','2019','2019-08-05'),
            ('788768646','02','2019','2019-08-18'),
            ('788768646','02','2019','2019-09-13'),
            ('788768646','02','2019','2019-09-15'),
            ('788768646','02','2019','2019-09-19'),
            ('788768646','02','2019','2019-09-25'),
            ('788768646','02','2019','2019-10-14'),
            ('788768646','02','2019','2019-10-21'),
            ('788768646','02','2019','2019-10-24'),
            ('788768646','02','2019','2019-10-27'),
            ('788768646','02','2019','2019-10-28'),
            ('788768646','02','2019','2019-11-03'),
            ('788768646','02','2019','2019-11-06'),
            ('788768646','02','2019','2019-11-18'),
            ('788768646','02','2019','2019-12-11'),
            ('788768646','02','2020','2020-01-01'),
            ('788768646','02','2020','2020-01-08'),
            ('788768646','02','2020','2020-01-09'),
            ('788768646','02','2020','2020-01-16'),
            ('788768646','02','2020','2020-01-17'),
            ('788768646','02','2020','2020-01-24'),
            ('788768646','02','2020','2020-01-25'),

            ('788768699','02','2019','2019-06-06'),
            ('788768699','02','2019','2019-06-07'),
            ('788768699','02','2019','2019-07-17'),
            ('788768699','02','2019','2019-08-23')

        ) t (Subscriber_ID, Member_Seq, Measurement_Year, Visit_Date)
), AllVisits as (
    SELECT *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Subscriber_ID ORDER BY Visit_Date) as [VisitSeq]
    FROM Example
), Report as (
    SELECT *, Visit_Date as [PeriodStart]
    FROM AllVisits
    WHERE VisitSeq = 1
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT a.*, 
        -- if not in the prior period, start a new 8 day period
        CASE WHEN a.Visit_Date > r.PeriodStart + 7 THEN a.Visit_Date ELSE r.PeriodStart END
    FROM AllVisits a
    INNER JOIN Report r
    ON r.Subscriber_ID = a.Subscriber_ID AND r.[VisitSeq] + 1 = a.[VisitSeq]
)
select *, 
    PeriodStart + 7 AS [PeriodEnD],
    CASE WHEN Visit_Date = PeriodStart THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as [IsFirstDayOfPeriod]
from Report 
where Visit_Date = PeriodStart
order by Subscriber_ID, Visit_Date
```

The query below gets most of desired records, but not all of them.  (This is where it misses a long string of close visits.)  I wanted to start here, but but I could not use a subquery or a group by in a recursive part of the CTE.  I would have to do something like the above, but the anchor would need both the sequence start and finish.  Then recursion for each anchor record would be within it's range.  I might try it someday.

```
    SELECT *
    FROM Example e
    WHERE NOT EXISTS( -- those with no prior within 8 days
        SELECT * 
        FROM Example x 
        WHERE x.Subscriber_ID = e.Subscriber_ID 
            AND x.Visit_Date < e.Visit_Date -- prior
            AND x.Visit_Date > e.Visit_Date - 8 -- within 8 days
        )
```